# tensorflow c++ try to create graph failed

Tags: c++, tensorflow

the compiler remind that function `CreateGraphDef` return the incomplete type `tensorflow::graphdef`,how can i solve this problem
the code like this:

```
GraphDef CreateGraphDef()
{
    Scope root = Scope::NewRootScope();

    auto X = ops::Placeholder(root.WithOpName("x"), DT_FLOAT,
        ops::Placeholder::Shape({ -1, 2 }));
    auto A = ops::Const(root, { { 3.f, 2.f },{ -1.f, 0.f } });

    auto Y = ops::MatMul(root.WithOpName("y"), A, X,
        ops::MatMul::TransposeB(true));

    GraphDef def;
    TF_CHECK_OK(root.ToGraphDef(&def));

    return def;
}
```

[Full source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpmM5.png)

Comment: Every time someone posts a *picture* of code, a kitten dies. Please don't kill kittens. Post properly formatted, *real* code that is minimal, yet *we* can copy/paste to reproduce your problem.

Comment: All Includes? The code https://pastebin.com/UQfsSAAC works perfectly fine here.

Comment: thank you ，it is the problem that i did not include all